# Alternative to ui-grid(doesn't support angular2/4)

Tags: ui-grid

I am using ui-grid.
We are migrating our project from angular 1 to 2, but ui-grid doesn't have angular 2 support.
please suggest free (MIT) license grid alternative for ui-grid.

Comment: Is "free" an absolute must? I have not seen any good(i.e production-ready) free grids for Angular2.

Answer (score 7):

I was researching this recently, since I have an application that I used ui-grid on, and may be upgrading to angular 2 soon.

I've found...

Angular Datatables
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

ag-Grid which has a free version https://www.ag-grid.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented UI grid(AngularJS) into angular 2 using UpgradeModule and it is working fine, and I have also done some modification into that for gridOption which we can sent gridOption from typescript to UI grid.

Please find demo application : https://github.com/Umesh-Markande/Angular-4-Ui-grid

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but in case some people are still looking for alternatives...

I'm the author of [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid), which is a wrapper on top of [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) but specific for Angular, it is most probably the closest you can get to UI-Grid. There's over 300 stars for the project and it's very well maintained with lots of Wikis and samples, I have constantly added new features for the past 3 years since its creation and most UI-Grid features, and more, exists in Angular-Slickgrid. It also has 100% unit test coverage with Jest and also multiple E2E tests with Cypress.

Ag-Grid is another good alternatives **but** their best features are simply not free (quite expensive too) which is the biggest reason that I've built [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) for our multiple projects.

See for yourself, here's a [Live Demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/) with 30 different examples

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Table component](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) in Angular Material. Check out [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-overview) to see how it supports filtering, pagination, and more.